# Is it wise to use animations in place of style for some of elements?

Tags: angular, logic, angular-animations

Just curious, it doesn't seem to be very smart, but at the same time, what if? Will it be a bad practice or just unnecessary one?

For example, take a div element and describe all its states (including hover and focus and etc) in separated animation file. While in a component file and its html write logic for when implementing each state?

Answer (score 1):

The only question you need to ask yourself is: "Can it be done easily with CSS?"

If the answer is yes, then by all means. Angular binding makes changing style, and animating with CSS, quick and easy. No point adding a dependency to the Angular-Animation module if none are needed.

What Angular-Animation module provide is a way to deal with more complex animations that requires many states or specific events such as when animation ends or begins. You can use the Angular-Animation module to create powerful dynamic animation queuing system by queuing up different states in an array and moving to the next state once an animation as ended for a certain component.

A simple example of that would be a box in the middle of the screen with 4 arrows button at the bottom of the screen that control the box position. Everytime you click a button, it moves the box for 1 second in the direction designated by the button. The problem here is that you want the movement to finish before the box start moving in the next direction selected.

For this, all you have to do is push into an array the new state of the box (Left, Right, Up, Down) everytime you press a button and, using Angular-Animation module, change the state of the box to the first state in the array when both these conditions are met: A) There is a state in the array. B) The current animation has ended.

Angular-Animations module can allow you to make dynamic changes on animation ending or beginning, allowing you to slice the state out of the array at the beginning and applying the new state at the end.